# Whats going on under the hood here for event handler? Does it apply to other functionality?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Hi so I am just wanting to understand how javascript/react is handeling whats going on  when I have a function triggered from an event . Im going to show three different code segements, 2 of which work, one of which didnt, and see if I am understanding them correctly. :)

```
setField(e){console.log("in setfield", e)}

<select multiple className="form-control" id="sel2" name="sellist2"
      onChange={() => this.setField()}>
```

this doesnt work because it is passing a null value to a function that expects a value, in this case e. however, if the function was just submitting something already in state, that would be reasonable way to do it.

```
setField(e){console.log("in setfield", e)}

<select multiple className="form-control" id="sel2" name="sellist2"
      onChange={(e) => this.setField(e)}>
```

this works because it is getting the event as e and then passes it to the function. How does it know to associate the event to e? does this functionality extent to other things when dealing with html?

```
setField(e){console.log("in setfield", e)}

<select multiple className="form-control" id="sel2" name="sellist2"
      onChange={this.setField}>
```

This one I really dont understand why it works, but it does. I am assuming that it inherently know to pass the event as default to the function. again does this inbuilt logic occur anywhere else, maybe not neccessarily for events?

Thanks again. Im new to javascript so it is interesting to learn all the idosyncracies of javascript. sadly most of then learning is through frustration of debugging!

Answer (score 1):

All functions in javascript can be passed an arbitrarily large number of parameters, even if the function doesn't do anything with them. For example, the following is legal, if useless:

```
function thingThatExpectsZeroParams() {
  console.log('hello');
}

thingThatExpectsZeroParams(1, 2, 3, 4, [5], 'six');
```

Six pieces of data were passed into the function, but nothing happened with them because the function didn't do anything with them. To get access to the values passed in, you just need to pick a name that you're going to call it. This name is local to your function and can be anything you want.

```
function callback(event) {
  console.log(event);
}

// I could also just have easily called it something else, and the code would work just as well
// function callback(quesoBurrito) {
//   console.log(quesoBurrito);
// }

callback('hello');
```

So when you set up a listener like this:

```
onChange={() => this.setField()}
```

Your function will be called, passing in the event object. But since your function doesn't give the first parameter a name, you have no way to access it, and then when you call this.setField, you pass nothing in there either.

In contrast, with this listener:

```
onChange={(e) => this.setField(e)}
```

Your function will again be called, passing in the event object. This time, you named that argument 'e', and can then do with it what you will, in this case forwarding it along to setField.

And when you do this:

```
onChange={this.setField}
```

You cut out the middleman. this.setField will get called directly, passing in the event object. Presumably, setField is expecting this, and does something with the object it was passed.

Answer (score 1):

It's not complicated.  Whatever Javascript function you assign to onChange will get called at the appropriate time and passed one single argument generally known as `e`.  You can give that argument any name you want in your function (or not declare it at all), but the first argument will be there.

So, when you do this:

```
onChange={() => this.setField()}
```

You are ignoring the argument passed to your event handler and then inside that event handler you're calling `this.setField()` which to no surprise does not pass any argument to `setField()`.  In reality, what's actually happening is this:

```
onChange={(e) => this.setField()}
```

> How does it know to associate the event to e? does this functionality extent to other things when dealing with html?

The DOM specification says that when an onChange event handler is called, it will be passed the `e` object as the first argument (whether you declare it or not, it's there as the first argument to the function).  This is just how callbacks work in Javascript.  The caller of the callback decides what arguments they are going to pass the callback.  It's up to you when you declare your callback whether you declare the argument and use it or not.  Regardless of how you declare it, the caller passes it.

For this section of code:

```
onChange={this.setField}
```

You are say that the function you want to be the onChange event handler is your `setField()` method.  So, no surprise, when the DOM calls that method, it will pass the event object as the first argument just like in the above example.

> This one I really dont understand why it works, but it does. I am assuming that it inherently know to pass the event as default to the function. again does this inbuilt logic occur anywhere else, maybe not neccessarily for events?

As described earlier the DOM specification is where this event handler is specified.  In the definition of that, it describes what arguments will or won't be passed to whatever callback function you register as this event handler.  This is true of all callbacks in Javascript.  The caller decides what it will pass to the callback.  This is not specific to this type of event handler.  Callbacks are used lots of places in Javascript.  Even something like `array.filter()` takes a callback and it's the caller of the callback (the implementation of the Array object in that case) that determines what arguments are passed to the callback.

Comment: you say that eventHandler will be passed the e object as the first param. does this mean I can pass other things to to the object, but still have access to e?

like:
    setField(cat){ field = e.target.value + cat}

Comment: @JamesRundle - No.  You don't control what's passed to your callback/event handler.  That's determined elsewhere in the implementation of the code that actually calls the callback.  That is not under your control.  It is what it is.  And, `e` won't magically be defined unless you name the first argument of your callback to be `e`.